# Creating rails like ActiveRecord methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What I'm trying to do is extend ActiveRecord models so that when creating a class I can do something like

```
Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  foo :bar
end
```

Then in a rake task do something like

```
if model.foo == :bar
   #do some stuff
end
```

The only way I've been able to do that is with something like

```
module Extender
  def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :fooed

    def foo(value)
      self.fooed = value
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    Include Extender
  end
end
```

Then in the rake task

```
if Model.fooed == :bar
  #do something now
end
```

That seems like a bad way of doing it though because then for every attribute I want to expose, I have to actually add two attributes. Am I doing something wrong, or is that the preferred way of accomplishing this?

Comment: If you're just using foo to store a value at the class level, why not use class_attribute?

Comment: so you want to set a class variable that can be used as instance variable?
Did i get it right?

Comment: @davidfurber I'm not actually using Rails just ActiveRecord and Sinatra

Comment: @FriendsSystems - that sounds about right. I want a property settable with the familiar syntax 'settings :args' that's available to ActiveRecord models.

Comment: why dont you use cattr_accessor?
http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor

Comment: With both cattr_accessor and class_attribute I get "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" which makes sense.